# huawei p9 lite (emui 4.1.1, Android 6.0) default gallery app add

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, settings, huawei

I try to change the default gallery app on my p9 lite mobile. I found the `Default app settings` menu, where I can override the default settings. But my problem that I installed an app ([total commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&hl=hu)) and I want to use that app for gallery, but unfortunately that is not on the list.

How can I add an app for that list? Or **how can I set installed Total commander for default gallery app?**

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total commander is not a gallery app! It's is a file explorer. How do you expect it to be listed as a gallery app.

You can use [QuickPic](http://alensw.com/en/) as an alternative gallery app instead.

Comment: Thx. QuickPic works. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that I helped.